# sx selector not working with Material UI DateTimePicker

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have this DateTimePicker component and I wanna change the color of all days in the calendar to the theme color:

```
              <DateTimePicker
                sx={{ "input": { color: "primary.main" }, "button *": { color: "primary.main" } }}
                slotProps={{ textField: { error: false } }}
                value={props.values.incidentTime}
                onChange={(e) => props.setFieldValue('incidentTime', dayjs(new Date(e.$y, e.$M, e.$D)))}
                label="Date of Birth"
              />
```

The color of the textfield text is changed. It also changes the color of the calendar icon. I checked with the inspector and the calendar days are button components, but they are white instead of the theme color.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `sx` prop, but you need to use `slotProps` for this. Try something like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DateTimePicker
      label="Basic date time picker"
      slotProps={{
        textField: {
          color: "secondary"
        }
      }}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

Here is the link with a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-monad-9vcqlm?file=/Demo.tsx

Comment: Yes it is wrapped in theme

Comment: I updated answer with a link to a working example, you were using a wrong prop it looks like